# Use comma to split numbers

Tags: number-theory

> All the three-digit numbers are written in the ascending order, from left to right, in a row such that each three-digit number is separated from the following number by a comma. How many such commas are present for which the digit immediately preceding the comma equals the digit immediately following it?

---

*What I got*:

The numbers should be in type $100, 101, ..., 999$. Such equal digits can only be $1, 2, ..., 9$.

- $1$: $10$ in total, i.e. $(101,102), (111, 112), ..., (191, 192)$
- ...
- $8$: $10$ in total, i.e. $(808,809), (818,819), ..., (898,899)$
- $9$: $9$ in total, i.e. $(909,910), (919,920), ..., (989,990)$

So the result I got is $89$.

---

However, the result turns out to be $90$. Which one did I miss?

Comment: You missed (899,900).

Comment: @AlexR. Oooooo!

Comment: @AlexR. Why not write it as the answer and I will accept it? It turns out this pair is very special, not the same pattern as all 89 pairs I counted. Hopefully, you can add some discussion on how to work out for such special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you're missing is the pair (899,900).